# How to change Drupal's user/foo/edit to user/foo/settings?

Tags: drupal

For a Drupal 6 site I'm doing, it seems more appropriate for the "user edit" section to be called "Settings" than "Edit".  I'd like to make this change, down to the point where the URL would be example.com/user/foo/settings. I've been mucking around in _menu and _menu_alter handlers and the like, but haven't found a clean way to do this.  Is there one?  Any advice out there (other than "don't do it")?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jim, what were your results with experimenting with `hook_menu` and `hook_menu_alter`?  Would you be ok with having both /user/foo/settings AND /user/foo/edit? Or you're looking to get rid of /user/foo/edit entirely?

Comment: I have to admit the main results of my experiments were confusion... I was able to get user/foo/settings mostly working, but there were issues surrounding tabs from the secondary menus that were presenting different sections of profile information.  To your other question, I'd probably prefer to make /edit go away, but could probably live with it (or catch it and redirect it to /settings)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yeah, the first thing that comes to mind is **Don't Do It**, especially if you mean eliminating ".../edit". You can imagine that other modules (especially contrib ones) might assume on **user/%/edit** in order to generate their links and stuff.

But if you just *have to* do it for some reason, then it'd have to be something like:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['user/%user_category/settings'] = $items['user/%user_category/edit'];
  $items['user/%user_category/settings']['title'] = 'Settings';
  $items['user/%user_category/settings/account'] = $items['user/%user_category/edit/account'];
  unset($items['user/%user_category/edit'], $items['user/%user_category/edit/account']);
}
```

This will essentially **eliminate** the original "/edit" callbacks.

A better option (since, like I said, other modules/themes/etc you install in the future might assume the existence of the ".../edit" URLs) would be to have both, with the new one being just a copy of the original:

```
<?php
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['user/%user_category/settings'] = $items['user/%user_category/edit'];
  $items['user/%user_category/settings']['title'] = 'Settings';
  $items['user/%user_category/settings/account'] = $items['user/%user_category/edit/account'];
  $items['user/%user_category/edit']['type'] = MENU_CALLBACK;
  $items['user/%user_category/edit/account']['type'] = MENU_CALLBACK;
}
```

Notice I changed the **original** ".../edit" items' type to *MENU_CALLBACK* (they're *MENU_LOCAL_TASK* and *MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK* originally), because if you leave them all as local tasks, then you will see two "edit" tabs in the user profile, admin menus, etc.

Clear the cache and good luck!

Comment: Very helpful -- thanks!  (And, yes, I went the "keep the /edit versions around...)  However, there's a catch -- what if I have some profile categories, as I do?  I tried adding some lines like -- $items['user/%user_category/settings/OtherCategory'] = $items['user/%user_category/edit/OtherCategory']; -- to what you showed, but the category tabs are not showing up on the user/123/settings page.  However, if I go to /user/123/settings/OtherCategory, I do get tabs for the categories I've defined, except for Account.  So it's very close; any advice?

Comment: Mmm that's another problem which I'm not quite sure I understand, but if you're now having problems with relation to menu tabs not being displayed, then it's most likely a matter of their menu items' type not being set to either MENU_LOCAL_TASK or MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK accordingly. Maybe with more info (a pastie of your module or something) I might be able to make a better guess.

Comment: Thanks much.  At this point, pragmatism has taken over, and I've defined page-user-settings.tpl.php where I'm (choke!) hacking the primary and secondary menus together by hand.  I needed to define a few more lines like $items['user/%user_category/settings/account'] = $items['user/%user_category/edit/account'] for the other secondaries, but it's working and isn't too terribly ugly. Yes, it's wrong/misguided/evil, but it's never going to be extended in a truly drupalish way, and I gotta move on from this. At least I'm not hacking core... :)